# Shutdown behavior termination in azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

Is there any option for shutdown behavior in azure vm. In AWS ec2 we have shutdown behavior as stop or terminate my instance.

**My Use case:**
I have a vm root image for every one hour few vms are created using the root disk and scheduled todo some task. once task is completed i will issue shutdown command inside my vm. 
**Expected behavior:** my instance would get terminated after my job is completed.

1. Any relevant solution/workaround will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST Api to stop your vm. Sample with classic:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/roleinstances/<role-name>/Operations
```

body:

```
<ShutdownRoleOperation xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <OperationType>ShutdownRoleOperation</OperationType>
  <PostShutdownAction>shutdown-action</PostShutdownAction>
</ShutdownRoleOperation>
```

[Shutdown role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157195.aspx)

Comment: Is this is the only way ?, Using rest end point there is probability of having network issues and consistency issues.

Comment: local shutdown will it terminate my instance?, For example : I am using linux  vm. I if issue shutdown -h or init 0 command. will this shutdown or terminate.